# Error on setting environment variables in Ubuntu

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I tried to add a path variable in /etc/environment on Ubuntu.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_31
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

After I quit the shell and login again, it seems the `$PATH` has been messed up. Many common commands like ls, vim don't work anymore. I run `echo $PATH` and the output is:

```
$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Apparently, the "$" is not parsed correctly here. I wanna keep using "$" as it provides certain flexibility. Is there a work-around for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2BAC8-etc.2BAC8-environment), "Variable expansion does not work in /etc/environment".

You would have to generate `/etc/environment` with a script to get the effect that you want.